# How to integtrate Clear case with Windows explorer on 64 Bit windows 7

Tags: windows, plugins, windows-7, clearcase

I want to use the Clearcase with Windows 7 so that I can check-in / check-out files from windows explorer.

Thanks,

Ram

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to this [compatibility matrix](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg21302974), ClearCase7.1+ is supported on windows 7.

Once installed, you will be able to access the ClearCase entry added on the Windows Explorer contextual menu.

[image: contextual menu with ClearCase]

However, the 64-bit version don't always displayed said contextual menu:
see [**technote swg21251833**](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21251833) for Windows 7 workaround:

> For Windows 7 and Windows 2008 R2, custom menus can be created as described below.
>
> The advantage of these menus is that they are fast, the disadvantage is that they are **static (non-contextual)**:
>
> REGISTRY EDITS:
>
> This solution contains information about modifying the system registry.
>   Before making any modifications to the Microsoft Registry Editor, it is strongly recommended that you make a backup of the existing registry.
>   For more information describing how to back up the registry, refer to Microsoft Knowledge Base article 256986
>
> Create a suitable custom menu using the Windows registry such as those listed below.
>
> Note: You may copy the entries below and save in a *.reg file.
>
> Sample registry entries (using Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00):

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase]
"subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd01]
@="Add to Source Control"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd01\command]

@="C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /addtosrc \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd02]
@="Checkout"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd02\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /checkout \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd03]
@="Checkin"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd03\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /checkin \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd04]
@="Uncheckout"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd04\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /uncheckout \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd05]
@="Version Tree"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd05\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearvtree.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd06]
@="Properties of Element"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd06\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardescribe.exe \"%1@@\""
```

> Merge the `*.reg` file (created from step #1) in the Windows registry as shown below:

[image: reg file registration]

> The ClearCase context menu should now be available:

[image: static menu]

Comment: I am getting "Cannot import C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\CCReg.reg: The specified file is not a registry file. You can import only registry files." error. Can you please help?

Comment: I got it resolved... forgot to add Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 at the start of file.

Comment: @Ram: I was about to write just that ;) Is it working now (the static menu)?

Comment: @ VonC - Yes .. it is working... but the only thing i would like to know if a special icon can be displayed for the files that are under CC.

Comment: @Ram: not that I know of for the classic Windows explorer (unlike TortoiseSVN or TortoiseGit, there is no special icon overlay applied in the Windows Explorer with ClearCase, 64-bits or not, windows 7 or not)

Comment: These paths should be changed from `@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\...` to `@="C:\\Program Files\\...`.  This is x64 windows, not x86.

Answer (score 0):

It works on my machine.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase]
"subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd01]
@="ClearCase Explorer"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearexplorer.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd01\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearexplorer.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd02]
@="Find Checkouts"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearfindco.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd02\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearfindco.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd03]
@="Checkout ..."
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd03\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe  /windowmsg A065 /checkout \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd04]
@="Checkin ..."
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd04\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /window $activewnd /windowmsg A065 /checkin \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd05]
@="Undo Checkout ..."
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd05\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /window $activewnd /windowmsg A065 /uncheckout \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd06]
@="History"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearhistory.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd06\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearhistory.exe  \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd07]
@="Version Tree"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearvtree.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd07\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearvtree.exe  \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd08]
@="Compare with Previous Version"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd08\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /diffpred \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd09]
@="Properties of Version"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardescribe.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd09\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardescribe.exe  \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd10]
@="Edit ConfigSepc"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardescribe.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd10\command]
@="cleartool edcs"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd11]
@="Mount VOB..."
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd11\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /windowmsg A065 /mount"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd12]
@="Unmount VOB..."
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd12\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /windowmsg A065 /unmount"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase]
"subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd01]
@="ClearCase Explorer"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearexplorer.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd01\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearexplorer.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd02]
@="Find Checkouts"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearfindco.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd02\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearfindco.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd03]
@="Checkout ..."
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd03\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe  /windowmsg A065 /checkout \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd04]
@="Checkin ..."
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd04\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /window $activewnd /windowmsg A065 /checkin \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd05]
@="Undo Checkout ..."
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd05\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /window $activewnd /windowmsg A065 /uncheckout \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd06]
@="History"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearhistory.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd06\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearhistory.exe  \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd07]
@="Version Tree"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearvtree.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd07\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearvtree.exe  \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd08]
@="Compare with Previous Version"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd08\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /diffpred \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd09]
@="Properties of Version"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardescribe.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd09\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardescribe.exe  \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd10]
@="Edit ConfigSepc"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardescribe.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd10\command]
@="cleartool edcs"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd11]
@="Mount VOB..."
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd11\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /windowmsg A065 /mount"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd12]
@="Unmount VOB..."
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd12\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /windowmsg A065 /unmount"



[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase]
"subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase\Shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd01]
@="ClearCase Explorer"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearexplorer.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd01\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearexplorer.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd02]
@="Find Checkouts"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearfindco.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd02\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\clearfindco.exe \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd03]
@="Properties of View"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardescribe.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd03\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardescribe.exe  \"%1\\\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd04]
@="Edit ConfigSepc"
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardescribe.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd04\command]
@="cleartool edcs"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd05]
@="Mount VOB..."
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"
"CommandFlags"=dword:00000020

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd05\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /windowmsg A065 /mount"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd06]
@="Unmount VOB..."
"Icon"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe,0"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\ClearCase\Shell\Cmd06\command]
@="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\RationalSDLC\\ClearCase\\bin\\cleardlg.exe /windowmsg A065 /unmount"
```